# Image in PDF generating via PHPExcel+TCPDF

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel, tcpdf

I am generating a pdf through PHPExcel and TCPDF. I have set an image on the file. The file downloads successfully, but fails to load.

The file is working perfectly without the image part of the code.

```
$test = (realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]).'/TA2017/application/images/logo.png');
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$objDrawing->setName('Logo');
$objDrawing->setDescription('Logo');
$objDrawing->setPath($test);
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('A1');
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
```

I have tried with APPPATH and base_url also.

After opening in notepad I got this

Message:

```
    imagecreatefrompng(./home/polymer/public_html/TA2017/includes/images/logo.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Filename: tcpdf/tcpdf.php

Comment: error message seems clear

Comment: I know... it seems clear and strange to me.. I have used $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] method for other files for require_once and they are being included without a problem

Comment: Perhaps use `dirname(__FILE__)` instead of the `$_SERVER` variable. It seems odd that you are getting the dot (period) in front of `/home`